# could not convert string to float in tabu search algorithm

Tags: python

I am having this error for the part in bold:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/appan/OneDrive/Documents/Year 3/AI Assignment Semester 1/Tabu Search/Tabu-search-on-Travelling-Salesman-Problem-master/TabuSearch2.py", line 238, in 
solution, value, exec_time = tabu_search("five_d.txt")
File "C:/Users/appan/OneDrive/Documents/Year 3/AI Assignment Semester 1/Tabu Search/Tabu-search-on-Travelling-Salesman-Problem-master/TabuSearch2.py", line 175, in tabu_search
graph, max_weight = read_data(input_file_path)
File "C:/Users/appan/OneDrive/Documents/Year 3/AI Assignment Semester 1/Tabu Search/Tabu-search-on-Travelling-Salesman-Problem-master/TabuSearch2.py", line 64, in read_data
link.append(float(tmp[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

```
Process finished with exit code 1

can you help please

import math
from random import randint
import time
from random import shuffle
#import numpy as np


###  Data Format is dict:
#           data[node_name] = gives you a list of link info
#           data[link_index][0] = name of node that edge goes to
#           data[link_index][1] = weight of that edge
def read_data(path):
    linkset = []
    links = {}
    max_weight = 0

    '''
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            print (line)
            link = []
            #tmp = list(map(float,line.strip().split(' ')))
            tmp=line.strip().split('  ')
            arr=np.array(tmp)
            print(arr)
            
            link.append(float(tmp[0]))
            link.append(float(tmp[1]))
            link.append(float(tmp[2]))
            linkset.append(link)

            if float(tmp[2]) > max_weight:
                max_weight = float(tmp[2])
            

            link.append(int(tmp[0]))
            link.append(int(tmp[1]))
            link.append(int(tmp[2]))
            linkset.append(link)

            if int(tmp[2]) > max_weight:
                max_weight = int(tmp[2])
    '''

    **with open(path,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            #print(line)
            link = []
            #tmp = list(map(float,line.strip().split('  ')))
            tmp = line.strip().split('  ')
            #tmp = np.array()
            print(tmp)
            '''
            for i in tmp:
                link.append([i])
            '''
            link.append(float(tmp[0]))
            link.append(float(tmp[1]))
            link.append(float(tmp[2]))
            linkset.append(link)
            #print(link)
            '''
            link.append(list(map(float,tmp[0])))
            link.append(list(map(float,tmp[1])))
            link.append(list(map(float,tmp[2])))
            linkset.append(link)
            '''
            if float(tmp[2]) > max_weight:
                max_weight = float(tmp[2])**



    for link in linkset:
        try:
            linklist = links[str(link[0])]
            linklist.append(link[1:])
            links[str(link[0])] = linklist
        except:
            links[str(link[0])] = [link[1:]]

    return links, max_weight


def getNeighbors(state):
    # return hill_climbing(state)
    return two_opt_swap(state)


def hill_climbing(state):
    node = randint(1, len(state) - 1)
    neighbors = []

    for i in range(len(state)):
        if i != node and i != 0:
            tmp_state = state.copy()
            tmp = tmp_state[i]
            tmp_state[i] = tmp_state[node]
            tmp_state[node] = tmp
            neighbors.append(tmp_state)

    return neighbors


def two_opt_swap(state):
    global neighborhood_size
    neighbors = []

    for i in range(neighborhood_size):
        node1 = 0
        node2 = 0

        while node1 == node2:
            node1 = randint(1, len(state) - 1)
            node2 = randint(1, len(state) - 1)

        if node1 > node2:
            swap = node1
            node1 = node2
            node2 = swap

        tmp = state[node1:node2]
        tmp_state = state[:node1] + tmp[::-1] + state[node2:]
        neighbors.append(tmp_state)

    return neighbors


def fitness(route, graph):
    path_length = 0

    for i in range(len(route)):
        if (i + 1 != len(route)):
            dist = weight_distance(route[i], route[i + 1], graph)
            if dist != -1:
                path_length = path_length + dist
            else:
                return max_fitness  # there is no  such path

        else:
            dist = weight_distance(route[i], route[0], graph)
            if dist != -1:
                path_length = path_length + dist
            else:
                return max_fitness  # there is no  such path

    return path_length


# not used in this code but some datasets has 2-or-more dimensional data points, in this case it is usable
def euclidean_distance(city1, city2):
    return math.sqrt((city1[0] - city2[0]) ** 2 + ((city1[1] - city2[1]) ** 2))


def weight_distance(city1, city2, graph):
    global max_fitness

    neighbors = graph[str(city1)]

    for neighbor in neighbors:
        if neighbor[0] == int(city2):
            return neighbor[1]

    return -1  # there can't be minus distance, so -1 means there is not any city found in graph or there is not such edge


def tabu_search(input_file_path):
    global max_fitness, start_node
    graph, max_weight = read_data(input_file_path)

    ## Below, get the keys (node names) and shuffle them, and make start_node as start
    s0 = list(graph.keys())
    shuffle(s0)

    if int(s0[0]) != start_node:
        for i in range(len(s0)):
            if int(s0[i]) == start_node:
                swap = s0[0]
                s0[0] = s0[i]
                s0[i] = swap
                break;

    # max_fitness will act like infinite fitness
    max_fitness = ((max_weight) * (len(s0))) + 1
    sBest = s0
    vBest = fitness(s0, graph)
    bestCandidate = s0
    tabuList = []
    tabuList.append(s0)
    stop = False
    best_keep_turn = 0

    start_time = time.time()
    while not stop:
        sNeighborhood = getNeighbors(bestCandidate)
        bestCandidate = sNeighborhood[0]
        for sCandidate in sNeighborhood:
            if (sCandidate not in tabuList) and ((fitness(sCandidate, graph) < fitness(bestCandidate, graph))):
                bestCandidate = sCandidate

        if (fitness(bestCandidate, graph) < fitness(sBest, graph)):
            sBest = bestCandidate
            vBest = fitness(sBest, graph)
            best_keep_turn = 0

        tabuList.append(bestCandidate)
        if (len(tabuList) > maxTabuSize):
            tabuList.pop(0)

        if best_keep_turn == stoppingTurn:
            stop = True

        best_keep_turn += 1

    exec_time = time.time() - start_time
    return sBest, vBest, exec_time


## Tabu Search Takes edge-list in a given format:
# nodefrom nodeto weight
# 0 1 5
# 3 2 4
# 1 0 3
# Undirectional edges should be written 2 times for both nodes.
# maxTabuSize = 10000
maxTabuSize = 500
neighborhood_size = 500
stoppingTurn = 500
max_fitness = 0
start_node = 0
# solution, value, exec_time = tabu_search("test.txt")
solution, value, exec_time = tabu_search("five_d.txt")

print(solution)
print(value)
print(exec_time)
```

Comment: Try debugging by printing the value of tmp[0]

Comment: when debugging by printing the value of tmp[0], it is giving these values:['0.0', '3.0', '4.0', '2.0', '7.0']
0.0
['3.0', '0.0', '4.0', '6.0', '3.0']
3.0
['4.0', '4.0', '0.0', '5.0', '8.0']
4.0
['2.0', '6.0', '5.0', '0.0', '6.0']
2.0
['7.0', '3.0', '8.0', '6.0', '0.0']
7.0
['']

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. *float()* can't handle lists or empty strings

Comment: Is there any other way to handle the file in terms of float please